# The inequality $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\ge 3$

Tags: inequality

Suppose $a,b,c$ are positive numbers. I would like to prove the following inequality in the most elementary way:

$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\ge 3.$$

I think I can prove using derivatives but I need to find a more simple proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the inequality between [the arithmetic and the geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means):
$$\frac ab + \frac bc + \frac ca \geq 3\sqrt[3]{\frac ab \cdot \frac bc \cdot \frac ca} = 3$$

Comment: Thank you very much! That's a really nice solution

Comment: @ESM You are welcome :-)